# Getting errror When install Postgis in Postgresql 14 from source

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gdal, geos, json-c

I'm trying to install Postgis.

I have install prerequisite:

- Geos 3.5.6
- Proj 7.0.0
- Jsonc 0.15
- gDal 3.0.0

This is logs when Configure Postgis:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/postgis --with-pgconfig=/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_config --with-gdalconfig=/opt/gdal/bin/gdal-config --with-geosconfig=/opt/geos/bin/geos-config --with-projdir=/opt/proj --with-libiconv=/usr/bin --with-jsondir=/opt/json --with-gui --with-raster --with-topology --with-gettext=no

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... (cached) /usr/bin/grep
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for cpp... /usr/bin/cpp
checking if gcc supports -fno-math-errno... yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-signed-zeros... yes
checking if gcc supports -std=gnu99... yes
checking if gcc supports -Wall... ^Cpos./configure --prefix=/opt/postgis --with-pgconfig=/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_config --with-gdalconfig=/opt/gdal/bin/gdal-config --with-geosconfig=/opt/geos/bin/geos-config --with-projdir=/opt/proj --with-libiconv=/usr/bin --with-jsondir=/usr/local --with-gui --
with-raster --with-topology --with-gettext=no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... (cached) /usr/bin/grep
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for cpp... /usr/bin/cpp
checking if gcc supports -fno-math-errno... yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-signed-zeros... yes
checking if gcc supports -std=gnu99... yes
checking if gcc supports -Wall... yes
checking if gcc supports -Wmissing-prototypes... yes
checking if gcc supports -ffloat-store... yes
checking if gcc supports --exclude-libs... yes
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... -lfl
checking whether yytext is a pointer... yes
checking for bison... bison -y
checking ieeefp.h usability... no
checking ieeefp.h presence... no
checking for ieeefp.h... no
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking for vasprintf... yes
checking for asprintf... yes
checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for xsltproc... no
configure: WARNING: xsltproc is not installed so documentation cannot be built
checking for convert... no
configure: WARNING: ImageMagick does not seem to be installed. Documentation cannot be built
checking for dblatex... no
configure: WARNING: dblatex is not installed so PDF documentation cannot be built
checking for xmllint... no
configure: WARNING: xmllint is not installed so documentation cannot be checked
configure: WARNING: could not locate Docbook stylesheets required to build the documentation
checking CUnit/CUnit.h usability... no
checking CUnit/CUnit.h presence... no
checking for CUnit/CUnit.h... no
configure: WARNING: could not locate CUnit required for unit tests
checking user-specified libiconv location: /usr/bin
checking iconv.h usability... yes
checking iconv.h presence... yes
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for libiconv_open in -liconv... no
checking for iconv_open in -lc... yes
checking for iconvctl... no
checking for libiconvctl... no
Using user-specified pg_config file: /opt/postgresql/bin/pg_config
checking PostgreSQL version... PostgreSQL 14devel
checking libpq-fe.h usability... yes
checking libpq-fe.h presence... yes
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PQserverVersion in -lpq... yes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  WARNING: You have set the --prefix to '/opt/postgis'. But we mostly
  ignore the --prefix. For your info, using the values determined from
  /opt/postgresql/bin/pg_config we will be installing:
    * postgis shared library in /opt/postgresql/lib
    * postgis SQL files in /opt/postgresql/share/contrib/postgis-3.0
    * postgis executables in /opt/postgresql/bin
------------------------------------------------------------------------
checking for xml2-config... /usr/bin/xml2-config
checking libxml/tree.h usability... yes
checking libxml/tree.h presence... yes
checking for libxml/tree.h... yes
checking libxml/parser.h usability... yes
checking libxml/parser.h presence... yes
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking libxml/xpath.h usability... yes
checking libxml/xpath.h presence... yes
checking for libxml/xpath.h... yes
checking libxml/xpathInternals.h usability... yes
checking libxml/xpathInternals.h presence... yes
checking for libxml/xpathInternals.h... yes
checking for xmlInitParser in -lxml2... yes
Using user-specified geos-config file: /opt/geos/bin/geos-config
checking GEOS version... 3.6.5
checking geos_c.h usability... yes
checking geos_c.h presence... yes
checking for geos_c.h... yes
checking for initGEOS in -lgeos_c... yes
checking for sfcgal-config... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
Using user-specified proj directory: /opt/proj
checking proj_api.h usability... no
checking proj_api.h presence... no
checking for proj_api.h... no
checking proj.h usability... yes
checking proj.h presence... yes
checking for proj.h... yes
checking for proj.h... (cached) yes
checking for pj_get_release in -lproj... yes
Using user-specified json-c directory: /usr/local
checking for "/usr/local/include/json-c/json.h"... yes
checking for json_object_get in -ljson-c... yes
checking for PROTOBUFC... no
libprotobuf-c not found in pkg-config
checking protobuf-c/protobuf-c.h usability... no
checking protobuf-c/protobuf-c.h presence... no
checking for protobuf-c/protobuf-c.h... no
unable to find protobuf-c/protobuf-c.h using
checking for protobuf_c_message_init in -lprotobuf-c... no
unable to link protobuf-c using
checking for protobuf_c_version in -lprotobuf-c... no
checking protobuf-c version... 0
checking for protoc-c... no
Cannot find protoc-c protobuf compiler on the PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
GUI: Build requested, checking for dependencies (GKT+2.0)
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.8.0... Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
Package gdk-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gdk-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gdk-2.0' found
checking for PCRE... no
TOPOLOGY: Topology support requested
RASTER: Raster support requested
checking GDAL version... 3.0.0
checking for OGR enabled... yes
checking gdal.h usability... yes
checking gdal.h presence... yes
checking for gdal.h... yes
checking ogr_api.h usability... yes
checking ogr_api.h presence... yes
checking for ogr_api.h... yes
checking cpl_conv.h usability... yes
checking cpl_conv.h presence... yes
checking for cpl_conv.h... yes
checking for library containing GDALAllRegister... none required
checking for library containing OGRRegisterAll... none required
enabling PostgreSQL extension support...
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating GNUmakefile
config.status: creating extensions/Makefile
config.status: creating extensions/postgis/Makefile
config.status: creating extensions/postgis_raster/Makefile
config.status: creating extensions/postgis_sfcgal/Makefile
config.status: creating extensions/postgis_topology/Makefile
config.status: creating extensions/postgis_tiger_geocoder/Makefile
config.status: creating extensions/address_standardizer/Makefile
config.status: creating liblwgeom/Makefile
config.status: creating liblwgeom/cunit/Makefile
config.status: creating liblwgeom/liblwgeom.h
config.status: creating libpgcommon/Makefile
config.status: creating libpgcommon/cunit/Makefile
config.status: creating postgis/Makefile
config.status: creating postgis/sqldefines.h
config.status: creating loader/Makefile
config.status: creating loader/cunit/Makefile
config.status: creating topology/Makefile
config.status: creating topology/test/Makefile
config.status: creating regress/Makefile
config.status: creating regress/core/Makefile
config.status: creating regress/sfcgal/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile.comments
config.status: creating doc/html/image_src/Makefile
config.status: creating utils/Makefile
config.status: creating raster/Makefile
config.status: creating raster/rt_core/Makefile
config.status: creating raster/rt_pg/Makefile
config.status: creating raster/loader/Makefile
config.status: creating raster/test/Makefile
config.status: creating raster/test/cunit/Makefile
config.status: creating raster/test/regress/Makefile
config.status: creating raster/scripts/Makefile
config.status: creating raster/scripts/python/Makefile
config.status: creating deps/Makefile
config.status: creating postgis_config.h
config.status: creating raster/raster_config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands

  PostGIS is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

 -------------- Compiler Info -------------
  C compiler:           gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -fno-math-errno -fno-signed-zeros
  CPPFLAGS:              -I/opt/geos/include -I/opt/proj/include  -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/local/include/json-c
  SQL preprocessor:     /usr/bin/cpp -traditional-cpp -w -P

 -------------- Additional Info -------------
  Interrupt Tests:   DISABLED use: --with-interrupt-tests to enable

 -------------- Dependencies --------------
  GEOS config:          /opt/geos/bin/geos-config
  GEOS version:         3.6.5
  GDAL config:          /opt/gdal/bin/gdal-config
  GDAL version:         3.0.0
  PostgreSQL config:    /opt/postgresql/bin/pg_config
  PostgreSQL version:   PostgreSQL 14devel
  PROJ4 version:        70
  Libxml2 config:       /usr/bin/xml2-config
  Libxml2 version:      2.9.10
  JSON-C support:       yes
  protobuf support:     no
  PCRE support:         no
  Perl:                 /usr/bin/perl
  Wagyu:                no

 --------------- Extensions ---------------
  PostGIS Raster:                     enabled
  PostGIS Topology:                   enabled
  SFCGAL support:                     disabled
  Address Standardizer support:       disabled

 -------- Documentation Generation --------
  xsltproc:
  xsl style sheets:
  dblatex:
  convert:
  mathml2.dtd:          http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd

configure: WARNING:  --------- GEOS VERSION WARNING ------------
configure: WARNING:   You are building against GEOS 3.6.5.
configure: WARNING:
configure: WARNING:   To take advantage of _all_ the features of
configure: WARNING:   PostGIS, GEOS 3.7.0 or higher is required.
configure: WARNING:
configure: WARNING:   For _most_ features, GEOS 3.6.0 is enough.
configure: WARNING:
configure: WARNING:   We recommend GEOS 3.7.0 or higher
configure: WARNING:
configure: WARNING:   You can download the latest versions from
configure: WARNING:   http://geos.osgeo.org/
configure: WARNING:
configure: WARNING:
configure: WARNING:  | You are building using --with-projdir. This option isn't standard and    |
configure: WARNING:  | might be incompatible with future releases of PROJ.                      |
configure: WARNING:  | You can instead adjust the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you   |
configure: WARNING:  | installed software in a non-standard prefix.                             |
configure: WARNING:  | Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PROJ_CFLAGS and     |
configure: WARNING:  | PROJ_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.                          |
configure: WARNING:
configure: WARNING:  | You are building using --with-jsondir. This option isn't standard and    |
configure: WARNING:  | might be incompatible with future releases of json-c.                    |
configure: WARNING:  | You can instead adjust the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you   |
configure: WARNING:  | installed software in a non-standard prefix.                             |
configure: WARNING:  | Alternatively, you may set the environment variables JSONC_CFLAGS and    |
configure: WARNING:  | JSONC_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

And this is Error

[image: Erro]

Comment: Postgres 14 isn't even in beta

Comment: I have tried with PG 12, but  I have the same error,

Comment: @vuongdingo in PG12 you should install postgis like this: `sudo apt-get install postgresql-12-postgis-3` (for postgis 3, obviously). After that run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` in your database. Does it help?

Comment: @JimJones What is the default password of postgres user? Where is the folder Postgis install to?

Comment: @vuongdingo there is no such thing as default password. You have to set it yourself after installation. What do you mean by PostGIS folder? It seems unrelated to your orginal post